# iPhoneX inputView wrong heigh

Tags: swift, uikeyboard, inputview

I have a simple ViewController

The problem is the code
print("HEIGHT (keyboardSize.height)") prints Height = 69

Why ?
I have set input view frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 30)
So I expect the heigh would be 30 but it is not.

The problem appears only on iPhoneX.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.inputView = SoftView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        addCustomKeyboardNotification()
    }

    private func addCustomKeyboardNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(customKeyboardWillAppearNotification), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(customKeyboardWillHideNotification), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    private func removeCustomKeyboardNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc
    private func customKeyboardWillAppearNotification(notification: Notification) {
        guard let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect,
              let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
            return
        }
        
        print("HEIGHT \(keyboardSize.height)")
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    private func customKeyboardWillHideNotification(notification: Notification) {
        guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
            return
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
}

class SoftView: UIView {
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.refresh()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        self.backgroundColor = .green
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 30)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: you also need to add the `safeAreaInsets` into your calculations as the keyboard will appear above the `safeArea` on iPhoneX

Comment: `viewController.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + 30`

Comment: So i have one more question. If i set input view frame height = 70 then keyboard height will be 70. That is what i expect. The question is why when i have set frame height < 69 the keyboard height will be 69 instead my value?

Comment: The question is not how animate layout when keyboard appears but why keyboard size has wrong height